# Как грамотно составить GET запрос к Google?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5

*Всем привет! Задумал я кодить* **bota** *поискового, кто знает, как составить запрос, чтобы* **google** вернул мне страницу с запрошенными данными, как-то так )

Какую библиотеку использовать? От примерчика не откажусь.

Comment: гугл неплохо обнаруживает ботов и банит ip с которых они приходят (начинает капчу запрашивать)

Comment: Запрос простой: GET, Google!

Comment: `ok, Google. GET!` Я думаю так

Comment: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Comment: Так не пойдёт ! в браузере опера когда набираешь такой адрес www.google.kz/search?q=%D/ гугл возвращает страницу ссылками в основном о языке программирования D  а из кода на питон если забить такой же url то результат начальная страница гугл вопрос что и как отправляет опера ?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [What are the alternatives now that the Google web search API has been deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4082966/4279)